# How to update a certain column value from values in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

**foos** table has the following columns `(id, value)`

**bars** tables has the following columns `(id, foo_id, min, max, calc_value)`

How to `update calc_value` to `"select value from foo where id=foo_id" + "x" + min + "x" + max` across all rows in the `bars` table

I am using the following function, but foo_id mapping is difficult

```
CONCAT_WS("x", "", min, max)
```

Comment: It is also difficult to follow you without sample data to illustrate. Your pseudo `WHERE` is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get if "x + min + x + max" should be concatenated to value or to foo_id, in the first case:

```
update bars b
set calc_value = (select concat(value , "x", min, "x", max)
                  from foo f
                  where f.id = b.foo_id )
```

In the second case:

```
update bars b
    set calc_value = (select value 
                      from foo f
                      where f.id = concat(b.foo_id, x, min, x, max )
```

In the first case you manipulate the string in the select in order to set in calc_value the ready-to-go value. In the latter case you build up the key you want to match with foo.id.

Hope this helps!